# Editing HTML DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My assignment is to modify the box provided by the instructor using Javascript. However, none of the changes I make on my Javascript file seem to work. I have named my HTML file `index.html` and Javascript file `javascript.js`. Here is what I have:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

        });

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.color:orange

        });

 document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0;

        });
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you ever get back the normal opacity?

Comment: The reset button should do that. But I still have to work on that. I suspect that all I have to do is add .addEventlistener and include all of the original styles, including opacity.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here: `document.getElementById("box").style.color:orange` . It should be `document.getElementById("box").style.color = "orange";`.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "orange";

});

 document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0;

});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is the button called BLUE making it orange? I feel like the instructor provided the JS and is testing the students.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I run the code snippet, stacks "mini google inspect" shows that the ":" in your javascript should not be there!

So your code should be

```
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "orange";

        });
```

instead of what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

        });

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.background = "blue";

        });

 document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0;

        });
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
  });
```

```html
<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px;opacity: 1;"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>


</body>
```

Check your syntax :)

Comment: I see that running the code snippet on here works. But when I try to run on my end by using the default browser, it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Moises, you should check your syntax of `document.getElementById("box").style.color:orange` to `document.getElementById("box").style.color = "orange";` and always check your close parenthesis or close brackets on your last line of your provided code `});`